# Debug assertion failed C - Not deleting

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that allows users to add a question that has 4 answers, right answer, date, author and level of complexity, also the program has functions for reading all the questions and deleting a question. When I choose the option add a question and i insert all of the characteristics the message box for the error appears it also doesn't allow me to delete or see the `.
questions. i need help.

Why is the following code not allowing me to delete a question?

```
 void edit()
 {

    char filename[2];
    int y;
    int q,ft,s,t, fr,d,a,l,tr,n,da;
    FILE *f, *f1;

    f=fopen("pff.txt","r");
    if (f==NULL)
    {
        perror ("Error!");
    }


    fscanf(f,"%d",&y);


    printf("           " );
    gets(question.name);
    n=sizeof(question.name);

    printf("Name : ");
    gets(question.name);
    q=sizeof(question.name);

    printf("Answer 1: ");
    gets(question.first);
    ft=sizeof(question.first);

    printf("Answer 2: ");
    gets(question.second);
    s=sizeof(question.second);

    printf("Answer 3: ");
    gets(question.third);
    t=sizeof(question.third);

    printf("Answer 4: ");
    gets(question.fourth);
    fr=sizeof(question.fourth);

     printf("Right answer (1-4): ");
    scanf("%d",&question.tr);

    printf(" ");
    gets(question.date);
    da=sizeof(question.date);

    printf("Date: ");
    gets(question.date);
    d=sizeof(question.date);

    printf(" Author: ");
    gets(question.author);
    t=sizeof(question.author);

    printf("Level (0-2): ");
    scanf("%d",&question.level);
    fclose (f);

    sprintf(filename, "%d.bin", y+1);
    puts (filename);    f=fopen(filename,"wb");



    fwrite(&q,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(question.name,sizeof(question.name),1,f);
    fwrite(&ft,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(question.first,sizeof(question.first),1,f);
    fwrite(&s,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(question.second,sizeof(question.second),1,f);
    fwrite(&t,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(question.third,sizeof(question.third),1,f);
    fwrite(&fr,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(question.fourth,sizeof(question.fourth),1,f);
    fwrite (&question.tr, sizeof (int),1,f);
    fwrite(&d,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(question.date, sizeof(question.date),1,f);
    fwrite(&a,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(question.author,sizeof(question.author),1,f);
    fwrite(question.level,sizeof(int),1,f);

    fclose(f);

    f=fopen("pff.txt","w");
    fprintf(f,"%d",y+1);
    fclose(f);


 }
```

Comment: You forgot to actually ask a question. What help do you need?

Comment: help realising what's my mistake and why does it fail

Comment: In what way does it fail? You say something about a message box, but what does that box say? You say you can't do things but don't tell us what happens when you try. Also, there's nothing indicating what the code you showed is us is *supposed* to do, so it's hard to tell what it's doing wrong if anything. What is the file format supposed to be? Lines?

Comment: The message box says  debug assertion failed
expression: (buffer!=NULL)

Comment: Does the message box have a `Debug` button? If not, can you install a debugger on your platform? I noticed that you have no error checking in your code -- for example, you don't check the return value of `fopen` to see if it succeeded. Adding that can help a lot.

Comment: it has try again, ignore

Comment: Then see if you can run the program under a debugger or install a JIT debugger on your platform. It seems your real question is "how do I debug C code?". And the short answer is that it depends on your platform and what tools you have/prefer.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. For example, you have not even shown the definition of important variables like `question`.

Comment: Are you sure your usage of `sizeof` is what you want? You cannot get the length of strings in this way, but this file format may be good for compatibility with future versions, which may have extended length of buffer.

Answer (score 0):

- The buffer `filename` is too short to store the name of file. It should be at least 16-character long if `int` is 32-bit long.
- Not knowing the actual definition, the line `fwrite(question.level,sizeof(int),1,f);` seems wrong because the address of `question.level` is passed to `scanf` with use of `%d` specifier, and I guess its type is `int`. You should include proper header and enable compiler warnings.
- You shouldn't pass `NULL`, which may be returned from `fopen`, to `fscanf`.
- You shouldn't use `gets` from the standard library, which has an unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, and is deprecated in C99 and removed in C11.

Try this (the problem that `gets` is used isn't resolved here):

```
 void edit()
 {

    char filename[32]; /* allocate enough buffer */
    int y;
    int q,ft,s,t, fr,d,a,l,tr,n,da;
    FILE *f, *f1;

    f=fopen("pff.txt","r");
    if (f==NULL)
    {
        perror ("Error!");
        return; /* avoid using NULL as file pointer */
    }


    fscanf(f,"%d",&y);


    printf("           " );
    gets(question.name);
    n=sizeof(question.name);

    printf("Name : ");
    gets(question.name);
    q=sizeof(question.name);

    printf("Answer 1: ");
    gets(question.first);
    ft=sizeof(question.first);

    printf("Answer 2: ");
    gets(question.second);
    s=sizeof(question.second);

    printf("Answer 3: ");
    gets(question.third);
    t=sizeof(question.third);

    printf("Answer 4: ");
    gets(question.fourth);
    fr=sizeof(question.fourth);

     printf("Right answer (1-4): ");
    scanf("%d",&question.tr); /* warning: don't place newline character after the number to be read here, or what is read to question.date may become not what is wanted */

    printf(" ");
    gets(question.date);
    da=sizeof(question.date);

    printf("Date: ");
    gets(question.date);
    d=sizeof(question.date);

    printf(" Author: ");
    gets(question.author);
    t=sizeof(question.author);

    printf("Level (0-2): ");
    scanf("%d",&question.level);
    fclose (f);

    sprintf(filename, "%d.bin", y+1);
    puts (filename); 
    f=fopen(filename,"wb");
    if (f == NULL) return; /* add error check */


    fwrite(&q,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(question.name,sizeof(question.name),1,f);
    fwrite(&ft,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(question.first,sizeof(question.first),1,f);
    fwrite(&s,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(question.second,sizeof(question.second),1,f);
    fwrite(&t,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(question.third,sizeof(question.third),1,f);
    fwrite(&fr,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(question.fourth,sizeof(question.fourth),1,f);
    fwrite (&question.tr, sizeof (int),1,f);
    fwrite(&d,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(question.date, sizeof(question.date),1,f);
    fwrite(&a,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(question.author,sizeof(question.author),1,f);
    fwrite(&question.level,sizeof(int),1,f); /* add & before question.level */

    fclose(f);

    f=fopen("pff.txt","w");
    if (f != NULL) { /* add error check */
        fprintf(f,"%d",y+1);
        fclose(f);
    }


 }
```